# Haskell data type of records to a list

Tags: list, haskell, types, tuples

I have a data type in Haskell, which I want to convert into a list of tuples.

My structure:

```
 data Projectdocs = Projectdocs {   
 docType            :: String,
 entityID           :: String,
 docURL              :: String

    }deriving Show
    --A sample projectdocs type
   Projectdocs{docType="txt",entityID="11012",docURL="www."}

    --The output I want to create
   ["Projectdocs"]
   [("doctype","txt"),("entityID","11012"),("docURL","www.")]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Automatically, for any record? Or just for this one?

Comment: this looks like you want something like JSON? because if so you should have a look at [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson)

Comment: I want to do it without aeson or other libraries @Carsten

Comment: and its Just for this one @Zeta

Answer (score 4):

If it's just for this one then you can easily hard-code it:

```
toTupleList :: Projectdocs -> [(String,String)]
toTupleList pd = 
    [ ("doctype" , docType pd)
    , ("entityID", entityID pd)
    , ("docURL"  , docURL pd)
    ]
```

Note that your proposed initial element `"Projectdocs"` doesn't have the type `(String, String)`, so it cannot be a part of  the list.

#### Example

```
λ> toTupleList $ Projectdocs {docType="txt", entityID="11012", docURL="www."}
[("doctype","txt"),("entityID","11012"),("docURL","www.")]
```